# Docker dotnet image container do not allow me to rebuild after change

Tags: asp.net, docker

I am new to docker, and I am trying to set a container to aspnet development. I just run yo aspnet on a folder and run:

```
docker run -i -t -p 80:5000 -v "$(pwd):/app" -w "/app" microsoft/dotnet /bin/bash
```

After that, I run the following commands to prepare to environment:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
dotnet run --server.urls http://*:5000
```

When I do some change to anything in the directory, even to a cshtml file, the changes do not reflect. If I try to stop the server and rerun it, I receive the error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet compile-csc @/app/obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/dotnet-compile.rsp returned Exit Code 1
/app/error CS2012: Cannot open '/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/app.dll' for writing -- 'Could not find a part of the path
'/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/app.dll'.'

Compilation failed.
```

I could notice that I cannot delete the app.dll file from the bin folder. When I try to delete it, it gives me the following error:

```
rm -R bin

rm: cannot remove 'bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/app.dll': No such file or directory
```

But, if I enter the folder, the file is there with 0kb size.

Do you know what am I missing to allow me to rebuild the app without need to restart the container?